# 4 col scrolling in a bootstrap one by one scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I found this beautiful sample of a bootstrap one by one scrolling that works smoothly.

http://jsfiddle.net/eaae76kx/

and I was trying to change it so that 4 cols appear at start and not 3.

could someone help me tweak the javascript accordingly

```
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
          interval: 10000
        })

        $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
          var next = $(this).next();
          if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

          if (next.next().length>0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
          else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
        });
```

since just changing css to 25% and changing col-xs-4 to col-xs-3 does not suffice and my javascript skill apparently do not suffice aither

Thanks

Comment: it appears to be a tweak of the bootstrap carousel, therefore your problem doesnt reside in this specific CSS or jquery, but in the carousel css/js of bootstrap itself, carousel is meant to show a slider img in the middle, so if you want to show 4 instead of 3 you should show the one that's active plus the previous, the next and the one after. complicated at first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit it by mine perspective, watch it and **important** thing i have made it in `bootstrap 4` not in `bootstrap 3`.

if you want this code in `Bootstrap 3`, ask me in comment.

**BOOTSTRAP 4**

```js
$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
         next = $(this).siblings(':first');
       }
        
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}
  
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
  transform: translateX(0);
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2>Bootstrap 4 Multiple Item Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Advances one slide at a time</h4>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**BOOTSTRAP 3**

```js
(function(){
  $('#carousel123').carousel({ interval: 2000 });
}());

(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      // wrap around if at end of item collection
      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: none;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.left {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-1,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-2,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-3 {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-1 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (transform-3d), all and (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-2,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) and (transform-3d), all and (min-width: 992px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/d6d6d6/333&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>          
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002040/eeeeee&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/40a1ff/002040&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: work very hard, don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Nisharg Shah, you are awesome